# Rails 4.1.1 (ruby 2.1.2) app won't run on Heroku app dyno

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I am having some troubles (second day I'm trying) with deploying just the basic app structure of rails to heroku. Upon this basic structure I'd later want to do some changes and enhancements to work, but for starters I wanted just to verify it's working properly.

My steps: 
1. I had some ruby and rails installed previously, but nevertheless I followed this guide for installing latest stable ruby and rails: http://railsapps.github.io/installing-rails.html
2. I have a ~/ruby/myapp folder in which I got the following versions:

```
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [i686-linux]
Rails 4.1.1
```

1. I created new project within this folder with

> rails new .

1. Got the project structure. Then committed it to Git repository.
2. According to [this](http://guides.railsgirls.com/heroku/) guide, I've added pg and rails_12factor to the Gemfile and recommitted it to Git.
3. At this point the app is firing up on my localhost ok.
4. I created heroku app and committed my git code to it. It ran bundle install.
5. Reaching at this point when my app already doesn't work on heroku, I saw bundle logs that it runs ruby 2.0.0. So following heroku support page, added

> ruby 2.1.2

To Gemfile - committed again
Heroku ran bundle install again

1. Did the heroku run rake db:migrate just in case - to build the db and so on.
2. Still heroku app says:

> The page you were looking for doesn't exist.
>
> You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.
>
> If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.

When looking at the heroku logs, here's the message:

```
2014-05-23T07:53:34.704093+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2014-05-23T07:53:34.704091+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
2014-05-23T07:53:34.704095+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2014-05-23T07:53:34.704097+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
2014-05-23T07:53:34.704098+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
2014-05-23T07:53:34.704100+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2014-05-23T07:53:34.704102+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
2014-05-23T07:53:34.704103+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
2014-05-23T07:53:34.704105+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2014-05-23T07:53:34.704106+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2014-05-23T07:53:34.704108+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2014-05-23T07:53:34.704110+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
2014-05-23T07:53:34.704122+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2014-05-23T07:53:34.704123+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2014-05-23T07:53:34.704125+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2014-05-23T07:53:34.704126+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-05-23T07:53:34.704111+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
2014-05-23T07:53:34.704113+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
2014-05-23T07:53:34.704114+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
2014-05-23T07:53:34.704116+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
2014-05-23T07:53:34.704117+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2014-05-23T07:53:34.704119+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2014-05-23T07:53:34.704120+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
2014-05-23T07:53:34.704127+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-05-23T07:53:30.745345+00:00 heroku[run.4509]: Process exited with status 0
2014-05-23T08:53:56.212847+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2014-05-23T08:53:56.213402+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2014-05-23T08:54:00.182694+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-05-23 08:54:00] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
2014-05-23T08:54:00.182702+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `block in start'
2014-05-23T08:54:00.182700+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `select'
2014-05-23T08:54:00.182706+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:160:in `start'
2014-05-23T08:54:00.182711+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:69:in `start'
2014-05-23T08:54:00.182704+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in `start'
2014-05-23T08:54:00.182708+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:14:in `run'
2014-05-23T08:54:00.182713+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
2014-05-23T08:54:00.182715+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
2014-05-23T08:54:00.182716+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
2014-05-23T08:54:00.182718+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
2014-05-23T08:54:00.182719+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2014-05-23T08:54:00.182721+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:8:in `require'
2014-05-23T08:54:00.182722+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
2014-05-23T08:54:00.182756+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-05-23 08:54:00] INFO  going to shutdown ...
2014-05-23T08:54:00.182847+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-05-23 08:54:00] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
2014-05-23T08:54:00.182883+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2014-05-23T08:54:00.182709+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
2014-05-23T08:54:01.539311+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2014-05-23T08:53:59.404723+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
```

I would very much appreciate your help, because this is the second day I've been trying to accomplish a task as simple as this with looking in forums (SE) and where not. And no effect. Although I've tried at least 4-5 times before I updated to ruby 2.1.2 and rails 4.1.1. And couple of times after that.

I'm becoming really, really frustrated with this config odyssey.

=========
Here as well is output from the git push heroku master

```
git push heroku master
Fetching repository, done.
Counting objects: 9, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 584 bytes, done.
Total 5 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.1.2
-----> Installing dependencies using 1.5.2
       Ruby version change detected. Clearing bundler cache.
       Old: ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [x86_64-linux]
       New: ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-linux]
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
       Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Using json (1.8.1)
       Installing minitest (5.3.4)
       Installing thread_safe (0.3.3)
       Installing i18n (0.6.9)
       Installing rake (10.3.2)
       Installing builder (3.2.2)
       Installing rack (1.5.2)
       Installing mime-types (1.25.1)
       Installing erubis (2.7.0)
       Installing polyglot (0.3.4)
       Installing coffee-script-source (1.7.0)
       Installing arel (5.0.1.20140414130214)
       Installing execjs (2.0.2)
       Installing thor (0.19.1)
       Using bundler (1.5.2)
       Installing hike (1.2.3)
       Installing multi_json (1.10.1)
       Installing tilt (1.4.1)
       Installing rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.2)
       Installing rails_stdout_logging (0.0.3)
       Installing sass (3.2.19)
       Installing tzinfo (1.1.0)
       Installing rdoc (4.1.1)
       Installing rack-test (0.6.2)
       Installing treetop (1.4.15)
       Installing coffee-script (2.2.0)
       Installing uglifier (2.5.0)
       Installing sprockets (2.11.0)
       Installing rails_12factor (0.0.2)
       Installing activesupport (4.1.1)
       Installing sdoc (0.4.0)
       Installing mail (2.5.4)
       Installing actionview (4.1.1)
       Installing activemodel (4.1.1)
       Installing jbuilder (2.0.7)
       Installing actionpack (4.1.1)
       Installing activerecord (4.1.1)
       Installing actionmailer (4.1.1)
       Installing railties (4.1.1)
       Installing sprockets-rails (2.1.3)
       Installing coffee-rails (4.0.1)
       Installing jquery-rails (3.1.0)
       Installing turbolinks (2.2.2)
       Installing rails (4.1.1)
       Installing sass-rails (4.0.3)
       Installing pg (0.17.1)
       Your bundle is complete!
       Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
       It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
       Post-install message from rdoc:
       Depending on your version of ruby, you may need to install ruby rdoc/ri data:
       <= 1.8.6 : unsupported
       = 1.8.7 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
       = 1.9.1 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
       >= 1.9.2 : nothing to do! Yay!
       Bundle completed (27.87s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       Asset precompilation completed (3.54s)
       Cleaning assets
       Running: rake assets:clean
-----> WARNINGS:
       No Procfile detected, using the default web server (webrick)
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-default-web-server
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> (none)
       Default types for Ruby  -> console, rake, web, worker

-----> Compressing... done, 22.0MB
-----> Launching... done, v7
       http://cookingdice.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku

To git@heroku.com:cookingdice.git
   432b16d..1d2b762  master -> master
```

Comment: Can you please post the output of the build process as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you get is a 404 error from rails, in production you dont see the rails welcome page.

If you create like a simple HomeController and render Hi or something, and set it as your root url, it will probably work!

**app/controllers/home_controller.rb**

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end
```

**app/views/home/index.html.erb**

```
<p>Hi</p>`
```

**config/routes.rb**

```
root to: 'home#index'`
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you modify production.rb to ensure static assets were being served:

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

Try to adding the following to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails_log_stdout',           github: 'heroku/rails_log_stdout'
gem 'rails3_serve_static_assets', github: 'heroku/rails3_serve_static_assets'
```

You are using Webrick server, try unicorn, make Gemfile production group something like:

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg' 
  gem 'unicorn' 
  gem 'rails_log_stdout',           github: 'heroku/rails_log_stdout'
  gem 'rails3_serve_static_assets', github: 'heroku/rails3_serve_static_assets'
end
```

Comment: Im not sure if the webserver is the issue, and the author already told that he had the 12 factor gem included. That one is serving those two gems your giving.

Comment: I agree with you @jvanbaarsen, I guess you are right.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Eki Eqbal. I was going to try your suggestions, regardless the first suggestion helped. But I guess it's not necessary if those two are contained in 12factor?